# Diophantine special problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

This is my another question on Diophantine equations. 
Prove the following great and special problem.

Let $D$ and $k$ be positive integers and $p$ be a prime number such that $gcd(D, kp) = 1$. Prove that there is an absolute constant $C$ such that the Diophantine equation $x^2 + D = kp^n$ has at most $C$ solutions $(x, n)$. Also prove that $x^2 + 119 = 15\cdot2^n$ has only six solutions.

Comment: A little more information, please. How do you know there is an absolute constant $C$ such that $x^2+D=kp^n$ has at most $C$ solutions? How do you know $x^2+119=15\cdot2^n$ has only six solutions? And what is great and special about these problems?

Answer (score 0):

These two problems are proposed by Yann Bugeaud in the $2007$ paper :[some open problems about diophatines equations](http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertsejh/07-workshop-problems.pdf) as open. This equation is also known as the generalized Ramanujan–Nagell equation, and there is a lot of work in this problem recently and it was confirmed that the number of solution is finite and there are reasonable estimation of the constant $C$ for some particular cases.

"This equation has a rich history and it has attracted the attention of several great mathematicians" so there is a lot of papers which can be found easily in the internet and I don't point to anything in particular here.